# Error ITMS-90135: The executable could not be re-signed for submission to the App Store

Tags: objective-c, node.js, cocoa, app-store, code-signing

OK, guys... So, I need your help.

I've been desperately trying to upload my latest app to the App Store and (after various, unrelated error messages) I'm now getting the following:

> Error ITMS-90135: The executable could not be re-signed for submission
>   to the App Store. The app may have been built or signed with
>   non-compliant or pre-release tools

Here's what:

My app uses Node.js (with several pre-"installed" Node modules, along with Node itself, all located in the `Executables` folder of my app bundle).

Now, I have codesigned all of those binaries and libraries (as reported by earlier error messages) with the appropriate(?) entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

And this is the command I used:

```
codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements "$ENTITLEMENTS" "${ROOT}$EXEC"
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: were you using pre-release tools (e.g. Xcode 7?); also, are you codesigning those binaries and libraries via Xcode before copying them into your final app?  [Here's a blog posting that talks about codesigning bundles the right way](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/) (without cheating via using "`-deep`").

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No, I'm *not* using "pre-release" tools. As for codesigning, I do it AFTER archiving, and per each individual file (that needs to be signed)